# ¿Como intercambio un valor en una matriz?

Tags: java, array, matrices

Necesito buscar una coordenada en una matriz y cuando la encuentre cambiar ese valor por 1, ¿Como le puedo hacer? Ya tengo el recorrido, si me puedes explicar por favor seria de gran ayuda
Les anexo una imagen de ejemplo de como debe ser la salida antes y despues del valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero ser muy especifico, gracias

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int AUX = 1;
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    
    
    int corral [][]= new int [m][n];
        
    for (int i = 0; i < corral.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("");
        for (int j = 0; j <= corral.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(corral[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    
    int posx = 0, posy = 0, c;
    System.out.println("Introduce el numero de chivas que hay en el corral");
        c = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce las coordenadas");
        for(int k=0; k<c; k++){
                posx = sc.nextInt();
                posy = sc.nextInt();
        }  
        
        int valor = 0;   
        for (int k = 0; k < corral.length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < corral.length; l++) {
                if (corral[k][l] == valor) {
                    

                    
                }
            }
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Pues puedes hacerlo dentro del mismo `for(int k=0; k<c; k++){}`, o ¿necesitas almacenar las coordenadas?

Comment: No es necesario almacenarlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no necesitas almacenar las coordenadas, puedes realizar lo siguiente

```
int posx = 0, posy = 0, c;
System.out.println("Introduce el numero de chivas que hay en el corral");
c = sc.nextInt();
    
System.out.println("Introduce las coordenadas");
for(int k=0; k<c; k++){
   posx = sc.nextInt();
   posy = sc.nextInt();
   corral[posx][posy] = 1;         
}
```

pides las coordenadas y luego accedes a esa posición en la matriz y le asignas 1, ya luego vuelve a imprimir la matriz para ver los cambios

```
for (int i = 0; i < corral.length; i++) {
System.out.println("");
   for (int j = 0; j <= corral.length; j++) {
      System.out.print(corral[i][j]+" ");
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y para imprimir la matriz con los valores intercambiados? ¿Como seria?

Comment: Pues lo mismo que hiciste al principio, después de declarar la matriz corral

Comment: Muchas Gracias!